# Creating a dynamically populated listbox from 2d string array with multible checkboxes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, listbox

First of all thank you for even reading my question. I did try searching but have not found a solution that would be clear enough for me.

So my problem is following: 
I have a 2d array storing pairs of filenames (full filenames with the whole path) they are organized in pairs so that fastas[1,5] and fastas[2,5] are meant to create one item in the listbox. I need those dynamically created items to have checkboxes (4 of them for each to be precise).

In more clear and simple way, I need a user to be ale to select pairs to compute for 3 different algorithms and get his selection back to pass the selected set to compute functions.

If anyone can provide insight, whole solution or point me in the right direction (resource) I will be very grateful. Maybe this is simple, but I am quite new to WPF.

Comment: This should be fairly easy, you should check out this link http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/ it has quite in depth coverage of simple listbox implementations that you might find helpful

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with related code, not only describe your setup in plain text.

Comment: Sorry for not responding for  long time, anyway thank you for your response was helpful and I manage to do what I needed through binding.